# Sum of a series with exponential and polynomial terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponential-sum

I have reduced the expression that I am working on to the following sum of series, which is definitely converging. It would be great if someone can help me out with this or suggest ways this can be done.

$\sum_\limits{i=0}^{\infty} (i+1)^{2}.e^{-(2i+1)^2}$

It might be possible to bound the above using the integral. Even a tight bound to the above would work for me.

EDIT : 
I am more interested in the following :
$\sum_\limits{i=0}^{\infty} (i+1)^{2}.e^{-\alpha(2i+1)^2}$
where $\alpha$ can be any constant (known). I am making this edit because for a constant multiplied the estimation approach by simply calculating a first few values won't work. In this case one would have to calculate first few values for different values of $\alpha$. Also, for different values of $\alpha$ it might not be able to always truncate after a fixed number. So, in essence, an analytical approach would be much more helpful.

Comment: Do you want a numerical evaluation? A closed form? Or do you just want to prove convergence?

Comment: A numerical evaluation, preferably. A closed form will work as well. Not the proof of convergence, I think that much I've figured out myself.

Comment: @Yves Daoust's answer seems pretty fine.

Comment: @OlivierOloa @ Yves  Please look at the edit I made to the question. The answer works for a certain value of alpha (as in the question). If an analytical solution is given then I'd be able to find the sum of the series as a function of alpha which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-1}+4e^{-9}+9e^{-25}+16e^{-49}\approx 0.36837308051278053458657911933771842$$ should be good enough.

The truncation error is

$$\sum_{i=4}^\infty(i+1)^2e^{-(2i+1)^2}=\sum_{i=4}^\infty(i+1)^2e^{-4i^2-4i-1}<\sum_{i=4}^\infty(i+1)^2e^{-64-4i-1}<2\cdot10^{-34}$$ as can be computed analytically.

---

You can obtain this estimate from
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty b^{i}=\frac{b^{n}}{1-b},$$
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty (i+1)b^{i}=\left(b\frac{b^{n}}{1-b}\right)',$$
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty (i+1)^2b^i=\left(b\left(b\frac{b^{n}}{1-b}\right)'\right)'.$$

Comment: Please see the edit I made to the question and also my comment above. Your method works fine, but if an analytical solution is given then the case of any alpha would be handled.

Comment: @shrughead: changing the question after the fact is bad practice.

Comment: I get it, but I thought it is better than to put up a new question instead.